# Heading row is not displaying in csv file

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

hy!
I have extract all the information from my database table into csv file.
Now i am trying to give heading to each row and wants to make it display like key,value pair.
For that, i make logic but that did not work.
Suggest the best possible solution please.

```
$sql = "select * from log";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

$fp = fopen('logInfo.csv', 'w');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) && $row = fgetcsv($fp))
{
    $all_rows = array();
    $header = null;

    if ($header === null) {
        $header = $row;
        continue;
    }
    $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);

    fputcsv($fp, $row);       
}
```

Comment: CSV files don't have key/value pairs, just raw data..... when you use fputcsv() only the array values are written

Comment: You might find a first row in the file listing the headers

Comment: @MarkBaker
I just want to give title to each row ? How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a headers row as the first line of your csv file

```
$header = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ($header === null) {
        $header = array_keys($row);
        fputcsv($fp, $header);       
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $row);       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're resetting `$header` each time.
Try this:

```
$header   = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ($header === null) {
        $header = $row;
        continue;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $header);
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
```

}

Comment: Error:.. Array to string conversion on line   fputcsv($fp, $all_rows);

Comment: Fixed the error. But i don't get how exactly you want them in the csv. The csv doesn't hold key-value pairs.

Comment: Sorry, i just want to display title of  each field  coming from database

Comment: This version puts the header after each line. If You want it only once, add the fputcsv line with the header above `continue`. And remove the one outsider the if.